# VM fails to boot after install when trying to install Debian with existing /home in encrypted lvm in vm

Tags: debian

I want to install Debian over an existing Debian install with an existing home partition in an encrypted lvm (to upgrade to testing), and I have been practising in a vm.

After trying to follow the advice on https://www.blakehartshorn.com/installing-debian-on-existing-encrypted-lvm/, I successfully reached the end of the installation, but when I try to boot into my system, I get the error(s) shown in the screenshot bellow.

[image: An image showing several lines of terminal output; starting with "sgx: There are zero EPC sections" then "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device".]

Pressing enter basically just repeats everything from "You are in emergency mode.".

Any idea what I did wrong/need to do?